# why projection tab is inactive in eventstoredb

Tags: projection, cqrs, event-sourcing, eventstoredb

As you can see in picture, my projection tab is inactive in eventstoredb tab.

Why?

And How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a server setting that controls if the projections runtime is enabled or not.

Check the [documentation](https://developers.eventstore.com/server/v21.10/projections.html#run-projections) about the setting.

[image]